# Can I have Kubernetes shut down pods that reach certain RAM percentage?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm dealing with a certain service that causes (seemingly unresolvable) memory leaks from time to time. RAM memory inside of the container/pod grows high and stays that way. The pod soon becomes unusable and I would very much like to configure Kubernetes to mark those pods for termination and stop routing to them.

For example, if RAM reaches 80% inside the pod can I configure Kubernetes to shut down such pods?

Any links you can share about this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: you can set resource limits for the pod. if the pod reaches this limit it will be killed by kubernetes

Answer (score 2):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: memory-demo
  namespace: mem-example
spec:
  containers:
  - name: memory-demo-ctr
    image: polinux/stress
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "200Mi"
```

To specify a memory limit: `resources:limits`
when process use more than 200Mi，pod will be killed because it is out of memory (OOM)

Answer (score 2):

There are two different types of [resource configurations](https://learnk8s.io/setting-cpu-memory-limits-requests)  that can be set on each container of a pod.

They are **requests** and **limits.**

Requests define the minimum amount of resources that containers need.

If you think that your app requires at least 256MB of memory to operate, this is the request value.

The application can use more than 256MB, but Kubernetes guarantees a minimum of 256MB to the container.

On the other hand, **limits define the max amount of resources that the container can consume.**

Your application might require at least 256MB of memory, but you might want to be sure that it doesn't consume more than 1GB of memory.This is your **limit.**

You can increase your request up to the limit range i.e, 1GB of memory. If the request is more than the limit, [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/) stops or throttles the pod.

For Example:

```
resources:
  limits:
    memory: 1 GB
  requests:
    memory: 256 MB
```